# Way to build, move, start Project and attach Debugger from Windows Machine on Linux Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, visual-studio, raspberry-pi

I have a Asp.Net Core Project on my Windows PC. The goal is to run and debug this app on my Raspberry Pi via remote access. The Pi has a Linux OS, if possible i don't want to use Windows iot. My pc and  the Pi are connected via SSH.

What i did so far:

1. Publish the project locally
2. Move the files to the Raspberry Pi
3. Start the .dll
4. Attach the Debugger

The Problem is that i have to fill and execute the swagger page on the pi and then i can debug on my windows pc. When i modify the code i would have to do all the steps above again. I am looking for a solution, where i can do all 4 steps automaticlly. The perfect solution would be to just press run in visual studio on my windows pc.

Can anyone give me any tips on how to solve this or what to research?

Comment: You maybe want to investigate ["PostBuild Steps"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2022) ?

Comment: Do you run the project "bare metal" or are you using containerization (docker?) ?

Comment: You need to look into how to script all of those steps, write that script, then run it using Post Build Events as mentioned above. [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish) first, then [copy the package using SSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106480/how-to-copy-files-from-one-machine-to-another-using-ssh), then start the package (again using SSH), then attach the debugger. Probably easiest to write the script as a separate file then call that in the post-build events, rather than trying to write the whole thing in the tiny box given

Comment: I have a script that I run from Cygwin terminal that uses rsync to copy files published locally to my RPi. Then I start a Blazor app from my local machine. Steps 1-3 are covered. I still haven't found out how to attach the debugger of VS  automatically (step 4). Doubt that anyone has a solution ready. But it would make Linux devs' lifes so much easier.